# CakePHP Retrieving rows for the current month

Tags: php, cakephp, timestamp

I have to following code to retrieve rows with timestamp of today:

```
    $interactives_presented_today = $this->find('count', 
                    array('conditions' => array( 'Tbsession.timestamp LIKE' => date("Y-m-d") . "%",
                                                'Tbsession.action LIKE' => "%Interactive",
                                                'Tbsession.username' => $user_id,
                                            ) )
                );
```

Now, I want to retrieve rows with timestamp of this month. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Comment: Try to extract month from the `Tbsession.timestamp ` and than compare it with current month

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think that's my problem, do you know to how extract it in cakephp?

Comment: let me have value of `Tbsession.timestamp ` !!

Comment: It's something like 2010-09-23 13:04:58, thanks @riky

Comment: ok now try yo extract month as i said by doing ->$mydate= Tbsession.timestamp; -> $month = date("m",strtotime($mydate));

Comment: Would you post a more complete code? I'm not getting it, I'm sorry, I'm a beginner here...

Comment: @Emkey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2794/discussion-between-riky-and-emkey)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('MONTH(Tbsession.timestamp)' => date('n'))
));
```

Answer (score 2):

this gets all rows that are less than 1 month old:

> ```
> $this->find('all',array(
>    'conditions'=>array($this->alias.'.timestamp >'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month"))
> ));
> ```

if you want to get this month:

> ```
> $this->find('all',array(
>    'conditions'=>array($this->alias.'.timestamp >'=>date('Y-m-00')
> ));
> ```

Comment: This would get all rows from the previous month, isn't it?

Comment: it would get all rows that are less then 1 month old. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: did you consider my timestamp value is something like 2010-09-23 13:04:58?

Comment: @Emkey: yep. Well, as long as you don't have timestamps in future date anyway. riky: why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysql [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format/) function.

```
$this->find('all',array(
'conditions'=> array('DATE_FORMAT(Tbsession.timestamp,"%m") = "'.date("m").'"')
));
```